# Can we use both spring data specification and spring data projection ? Does spring boot support this?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications, spring-projections

Can we use both spring data specification and spring data projection ? Does spring boot support this?

I want to use specification for filtering and selecting only the columns I needed from the table. So to get only the selected columns, I  want to use projection. Can someone let me know how to achieve this? Im new to spring and learning things. Kindly guide me

I have created a project like below,

my entity class:

```
@Entity

@Table(name="Customer")

public class Customer {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

my specification service class:

```
@Service
public class SpecificationService {

    public static Specification<Customer> getCustomerSpecification(String name) {
    
        return new Specification<Customer>() {
    
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                         CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    
                Path<String> custId = root.get("id");
                Path<Integer> customerName = root.get("name");
                query.multiselect(custId.alias("CustomerId"),customerName.alias("CustomerName"),
                criteriaBuilder.count(criteriaBuilder.literal(1)).alias("Count"));
    
                final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
                if (name != null && !name.equals("")) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), name));
                }
    
                query.groupBy(custId, customerName);
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

my customer service class:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;
    
    public void checkSpecification(){
        Specification<Customer> spec = SpecificationService.getCustomerSpecification("USA");
        List<CustomerProjection> projections = repository.getCustomers(spec);
    
    }

}
```

my repository class,

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository\<Customer, Integer\>, JpaSpecificationExecutor\<Customer\> {

    List<CustomerProjection> getCustomers(Specification<Customer> spec);

}
```

my projection class,

```
public interface CustomerProjection {

    String getId();


    String getName();

    Integer getCount();
}
```

I'm getting the below error :

> No property 'getCustomers' found for type 'Customer'